# How to type Non-English text in a password EditText with android:inputType="textPassword"

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, persian, non-english

I have an EditText with "textPassword" inputType in my app and I tried to set a non-english password but the inputType didn't allow me to choose another language.
Maybe my app users prefer to set a persian password.

[See The Picture, Please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdCd3.jpg)

Any Ideas?

Comment: did you try pattern

Comment: @ozi: No, I didn't. How can I try it?

Comment: I tried, and password edittext accept my special char (ü) What was your special char ?

Comment: @ozi: It doesn't let me to change the language, at all!!! See the picture that I've just uploaded in the post, please.

Comment: please look @marmor answer below, if it is ok for you, accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inputType` is considered as a **hint** to the keyboard app on how to treat a specific text-field, even if some keyboards do allow non-english passwords, you can't count on all keyboard apps to behave like that.

Instead of using the `inputType`, set the `password` field to `true`, this will cause the characters to be hidden from the screen, but will allow you to get any input, you should probably also turn off suggestions (using the `inputType` field):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textShortMessage|textNoSuggestions"
    android:password="true"/>
```

**UPDATE**

You can create a plain `EditText` with some textual `inputType`, and just set the characters to appear as dots instead of plain text:

```
EditText passwordView = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.password);
passwordView.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. it dosn't let me to change the language, too. whether using inputType or not. and the android:password is deprecated.